# I am trying to return 3 values from a function

Tags: vb.net, function, visual-studio-2017, return-value

I don't know if this is possible but i have this code like 4 or 5 times in my program but with different DOhav*** variables. I am trying to condense it to 1 function with a general DOhavART,DOhavART2,DOhavART3 variables to cover the variables. I am passing the values to it that it needs to complete the function. But I can only receive 1 variable back in return. I have searched online trying various things like using an array function or building a structure or building a large string from the 3 and splitting it when it returns but these don't work in a way I can use. The way it works is it looks to a set of folders to see it contains the correct images to match a system(sysSELsh), a game(RnameSH) and they type of image(ArtTYPE)

```
For Each foundDirectory In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories((lbPath & "\Images\" & Mid(sysSELsh, 1, Len(sysSELsh) - 4) & "\Box - Front\"))
```

by the end it should have 3 files with full path to return (which it does) but I can't retrieve 3 variables when it returns, when it returns it checks to see if any of the 3 files exist then add it to the listbox with a yes or no. There has to be 3 returns as that's how many different ways the file could be named or structured. I have it working in 5 different sections of code but with individual variables and everything else in the code is the same.There is actually like 20 folders to search through for all the different types of images so condensing it to a function is my big goal.

```
Public Function FINDArtTYPE(ByVal sysSELsh As String, ByVal RnameSH As String, ByVal ArtTYPE As String) As String

    Dim extFIND = RnameSH.Substring(RnameSH.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
    Dim RepSTR As String = ""
    Dim DOhavART As String = ""
    Dim DOhavART2 As String = ""
    Dim DOhavART3 As String = ""

    If Len(extFIND) = 2 Then

        DOhavART = lbPath & "\Images\" & Mid(sysSELsh, 1, Len(sysSELsh) - 4) & ArtTYPE & Mid(RnameSH, 1, Len(RnameSH) - 3) & ".PNG"

    ElseIf Len(extFIND) = 3 Then

        DOhavART = lbPath & "\Images\" & Mid(sysSELsh, 1, Len(sysSELsh) - 4) & ArtTYPE & Mid(RnameSH, 1, Len(RnameSH) - 4) & ".PNG"

    End If

    If FileExists(DOhavART) = False Then

        DOhavART2 = lbPath & "\Images\" & Mid(sysSELsh, 1, Len(sysSELsh) - 4) & ArtTYPE & DBid & "-01.PNG"

        If InStr(3, DOhavART2, ":") <> 0 Then RepSTR = Replace(DOhavART2, ": ", "_ ") : If RepSTR <> "" Then DOhavART2 = RepSTR : RepSTR = ""
        If InStr(3, DOhavART2, "'") <> 0 Then RepSTR = Replace(DOhavART2, "'", "_") : If RepSTR <> "" Then DOhavART2 = RepSTR : RepSTR = ""
        If InStr(3, DOhavART2, "/") <> 0 Then RepSTR = Replace(DOhavART2, "/", "_") : If RepSTR <> "" Then DOhavART2 = RepSTR : RepSTR = ""
        If InStr(3, DOhavART2, " / ") <> 0 Then RepSTR = Replace(DOhavART2, " / ", " _ ") : If RepSTR <> "" Then DOhavART2 = RepSTR : RepSTR = ""

    End If

    If FileExists(DOhavART) = False And FileExists(DOhavART2) = False Then

        For Each foundDirectory In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories((lbPath & "\Images\" & Mid(sysSELsh, 1, Len(sysSELsh) - 4) & ArtTYPE))

            Dim FileCount As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(foundDirectory & "\").Length

            If FileCount > 0 Then

                If Len(extFIND) = 2 Then

                    DOhavART = foundDirectory & "\" & Mid(RnameSH, 1, Len(RnameSH) - 3) & ".PNG"

                    If FileExists(DOhavART) = True Then DOhavART3 = DOhavART

                ElseIf Len(extFIND) = 3 Then

                    DOhavART = foundDirectory & "\" & Mid(RnameSH, 1, Len(RnameSH) - 4) & ".PNG"

                    If FileExists(DOhavART) = True Then DOhavART3 = DOhavART

                End If

                If FileExists(DOhavART) = False And FileExists(DOhavART3) = False Then

                    DOhavART2 = (foundDirectory & "\" & DBid & "-01.PNG")

                    If InStr(3, DOhavART2, ":") <> 0 Then RepSTR = Replace(DOhavART2, ": ", "_ ") : If RepSTR <> "" Then DOhavART2 = RepSTR : RepSTR = ""
                    If InStr(3, DOhavART2, "'") <> 0 Then RepSTR = Replace(DOhavART2, "'", "_") : If RepSTR <> "" Then DOhavART2 = RepSTR : RepSTR = ""
                    If InStr(3, DOhavART2, "/") <> 0 Then RepSTR = Replace(DOhavART2, "/", "_") : If RepSTR <> "" Then DOhavART2 = RepSTR : RepSTR = ""
                    If InStr(3, DOhavART2, " / ") <> 0 Then RepSTR = Replace(DOhavART2, " / ", " _ ") : If RepSTR <> "" Then DOhavART2 = RepSTR : RepSTR = ""

                    If FileExists(DOhavART2) = True Then DOhavART3 = DOhavART2

                End If

            End If

        Next

    End If

    Return DOhavART
    Return DOhavART2
    Return DOhavART3

End Function
```

Thanks for any help you guys can give with this.

Comment: If you want to get multiple values out of a function then you have two choices. You can return a single object that contains those values, which might be an array or collection or `Tuple` of custom type with multiple properties. The other option is to use multiple `ByRef` parameters instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried before posting here to implement the array but i don't know if the array should be implemented just at the end around the return part or do i have to change the code to suit an array. i also had a look at the tuple thing thing but i am new to this and didn't really understand that at all.

Comment: [Tuples as method return values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples#tuples-as-method-return-values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return a `List(Of String)`.

First of all redefine your function declaration:

```
Public Function FINDArtTYPE(ByVal sysSELsh As String, ByVal RnameSH As String, ByVal ArtTYPE As String) As List(Of String)
```

Then in the beginning of your function add:

```
Dim f As New List(Of String)
```

And then add as many elements as you like in your code:

```
f.Add("something")
```

And finally: `Return f`

The calling procedure just has to figure how many items are returned by the function, and loop on them as needed.

If you want to return multiple variables of different types at the same time, then you can simply define a custom **structure**.

Comment: If you're going to return a collection from a method then a `ReadOnlyCollection(Of T)` is a more appropriate option than `List(Of T)`. Using the latter is not the end of the world but a `List(Of T)` is intended for items to be added, removed and replace, which is not appropriate for fixed results. A `ReadOnlyCollection(Of T)` is like a `List(Of T)` that can't be modified.

Comment: *"The calling procedure just has to figure how many items are returned by the function"*. Not really. A `For Each` loop will access each item with out your having to know how many there are.

Comment: thanks for the help guys, so i am calling the function and getting the 3 items returned properly. just trying to figure out how to read it on its return.
if i use :

 `DOhavBOX = FINDArtTYPE(sysSELsh, RnameSH, ArtTYPE:="\Box - Front\").Item(0)
                    DOhavBOX2 = FINDArtTYPE(sysSELsh, RnameSH, ArtTYPE:="\Box - Front\").Item(1)
                    DOhavBOX3 = FINDArtTYPE(sysSELsh, RnameSH, ArtTYPE:="\Box - Front\").Item(2)`

it goes through the function 3 times.

the for each loop 
`For Each FINDArtTYPE(sysSELsh, RnameSH, ArtTYPE:="\Box - Front\").Item`
gives me an error

Comment: after a lot of trial and error, i can't get this to read the 3 values using the for each loop. I can't get the syntax correct for the loop to not show an error ?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/list-vbnet) for example, see section 'VB.NET program that uses Insert method'. There is an example that shows how to use and loop on `List(Of String)`

Comment: thanks but i have tried that, i cant find the correct way to retrieve the 3 variables after return from the Function. The example you show is using it in the same sub not reading it after it returns ?

Comment: From another sub, define another `New List(Of String)` variable and call your function eg: `Dim results As New List(Of String) = FINDArtTYPE(...)`.  And then loop on `results`, which is what the function returns.

Comment: to Anonymous that's done it, many many thanks so the answer was to make a list of the list you sent back, sorry for being dumb, i'm new to this level of programming. many thanks for the help :)